# How to access two different routines in two files in Trace32 CMM scripts

Tags: scripting, trace32, lauterbach

I have two files in two different floder locations in Trace32. I execute cd.do file_name subroutine_name in Trace32. The trace32 takes the location of first command executed as the folder from which the following commands needs to be executed. How can I execute the routines from two different folders.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you should simply use `DO <myscript.cmm>` instead of `CD.DO <myscript.cmm>`.

- `DO <myscript.cmm>` executes the script at the given location but keeps the current working path.
- `CD.DO <myscript.cmm>` changes the working path to the location of the given script and then executes the script.

However I would recommend to write your scripts in a way that it doesn't matter if they are called with `CD.DO` or just `DO`. You can achieve that with either absolute paths or with paths relative to the script locations. (I prefer the 2nd one.)

So imagine the following file structure:

```
C:\t32\myscripts\start.cmm
C:\t32\myscripts\folder1\routines.cmm
C:\t32\myscripts\folder2\loadapp.cmm
C:\t32\myscripts\folder2\application.elf
```

You can cope this structure with absolute paths like that:

**start.cmm**:

```
DO "C:/t32/myscripts/folder1/routines.cmm" subroutine_A
DO "C:/t32/myscripts/folder2/loadapp.cmm"
```

**folder2/loadapp.cmm**:

```
Data.LOAD.Elf "C:/t32/myscripts/folder2/application.elf"
DO "C:/t32/myscripts/folder1/routines.cmm" subroutine_B
```

With relative paths you could use the prefix "~~~~" before accessing other files relative from the location of the currently executed PRACTICE script. The "~~~~" is replaced with the path of the currently executed script (just like "~" stands for your home directory.) There is also a  function OS.PPD() which gives you the directory of the currently executed PRACTICE script.

So above situation with relative paths look like that:

**start.cmm**:

```
DO "~~~~/folder1/routines.cmm subroutine_A"
DO "~~~~/folder2/loadapp.cmm"
```

**folder2/loadapp.cmm**:

```
Data.LOAD.Elf "~~~~/application.elf"
DO "~~~~/../folder1/routines.cmm" subroutine_B
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good guide here on how to script in Trace32.
http://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/practice_user.pdf

I do not understand why you need to have them in two different folders, shouldn't it be solved by just have it in the same folder?

Comment: I have them in various folders. I have tried using chdir for changing the directory so that the routine from files in other folder could be executed. This creates the problem as I can use the routines available from only one folder.

Comment: I do not think the scripting language is made for using routines from different folders, it is not advanced enough. I know it is duplication but does it work fine if you just move it to the same folder?

Comment: Using routines from different folders is definitely possible. I suggested a solution (See above or below).  Aabha Geed, could you please make you question more precise? Since you haven't accepted my answer, I assume I misunderstood your request...